# Using Ninject with a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, ninject

Any good examples of using Ninject with a Windows Service? I'm not sure what if any extensions I need. Also, not sure what the Composition Root should be? Any good examples of using Ninject with a Windows service out there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A windows service does not differ much from a regular command line application in regard to dependency injection. The straight-forward composition root is your `Main` method.

The way I usually have done it is create the `StandardKernel` there with a module in which my dependencies are resolved. Then use `kernel.Get` to resolve the top level dependencies - everything else will follow from there:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new FooModule());
    var barDependency = kernel.Get<Bar>();

    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new FooService(barDependency) };
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Comment: Does Microsoft have a way to inject Ninject modules (or the kernel) higher up so you don't have to do any service locating? (not a big deal for just a couple of dependency - just curious)

Comment: Nope. Not that you are starting up much like a console app. You could make take an abstract factory (or factory method) pattern approach to creating your service, if you need to do so.

Comment: Dan, the Main method is the starting point. The solutions for web applications etc. are actually workarounds because a web application doesn't have a good starting point.

Comment: Why not `ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { kernel.Get<FooService>() };`? In case the service's constructor arguments change...

Comment: I actually have a situation when on production the creation of `barDependency` takes over 30s and the service does not start at all (not responded in a timely fashion). This makes me wonder if creating the service this way is a good idea (or is my case an isolated example of rogue Ninject bindinsgs/EF problems/...)

Answer (score 1):

Using Ninject with TopShelf.. run vs install(start)
I faced a strange issue where `> MyService.exe run` 
works fine with the code  `Kernel.Bind(handlers => { var bindings = handlers.From("abc.dll") ... }`

But when i start the service after installing using `> MyService.exe install`

it could not resolve the bindings mentioned in Ninject assembly scanning.

After a few hours of breaking my head...

changing the `.From(...)` to `.FromAssembliesMatching(...)` i could start the service successfully.

Hope it helps someone.